# VMware 5.5 Host Not Updating Time From NTP

Tags: vmware-esxi, ntp

I have 2 HP ProLiant VMware 5.5 hosts and I have configured the time sync on them to use NTP.  I have pointed the NTP to the n.north-america.pool.ntp.org servers.  I have restarted the time service and waited 15 minutes but the time is still out by 6 minutes (currently anyway).  The ntp.conf file looks like this:

```
restrict default kod nomodify notrap nopeer
restrict 127.0.0.1
server 0.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 1.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 2.north-america.pool.ntp.org
server 3.north-america.pool.ntp.org
driftfile /etc/ntp.drift
```

I have looked at the VMware NTP troubleshooting guide and the watch ntpq -q localhost command shows the following:

```
Every 2s: ntpq -p localhost
2016-05-20 17:39:28

     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
+utcnist2.colora .NIST.           1 u   42   64  377  111.955  347166. 166.746
+nox.prolixium.c 200.98.196.212   2 u   42   64  377   56.777  347187. 163.313
 triangle.kansas 128.252.19.1     2 u  114   64  332  105.921  347142. 155243.
*131.107.13.100  .ACTS.           1 u   40   64  377  103.846  347195. 165.405
```

The offset is always 347K out.  I have also looked in syslog.log and the only messages I see are the following:

```
2016-05-20T16:36:58Z root: ntpd Stopping ntpd
2016-05-20T16:36:58Z watchdog-ntpd: Watchdog for ntpd is now 950158
2016-05-20T16:36:58Z watchdog-ntpd: Terminating watchdog process with PID 950158
2016-05-20T16:36:58Z watchdog-ntpd: [950158] Signal received: exiting the watchdog
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z ntpd[950186]: ntpd exiting on signal 1
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z root: ntpd Starting ntpd
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z watchdog-ntpd: [956340] Begin '/sbin/ntpd ++group=ntpd -g -n -c /etc/ntp.conf -f /etc/ntp.drift', min-uptime = 60, max-quick-failures = 1, max-total-failures = 100, bg_pid_file = ''
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z watchdog-ntpd: Executing '/sbin/ntpd ++group=host/vim/vmvisor/ntpd -g -n -c /etc/ntp.conf -f /etc/ntp.drift'
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z ntpd[956363]: ntpd 4.2.6p2@1.2194-o Tue Mar  3 09:11:43 UTC 2015 (1)
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z ntpd[956363]: proto: precision = 0.520 usec
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z ntpd[956363]: Listen and drop on 0 v4wildcard 0.0.0.0 UDP 123
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z ntpd[956363]: Listen normally on 1 lo0 127.0.0.1 UDP 123
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z ntpd[956363]: Listen normally on 2 vmk0 172.16.120.2 UDP 123
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z ntpd[956363]: Listen normally on 3 vmk1 172.16.180.23 UDP 123
2016-05-20T16:36:59Z ntpd[956363]: Listen normally on 4 vmk2 172.16.180.24 UDP 123

2016-05-20T16:42:01Z ntpd[956363]: 128.138.141.172 interface 172.16.180.23 -> 172.16.120.2
2016-05-20T16:42:01Z ntpd[956363]: 131.107.13.100 interface 172.16.180.23 -> 172.16.120.2
2016-05-20T16:42:01Z ntpd[956363]: 45.79.10.228 interface 172.16.180.23 -> 172.16.120.2
2016-05-20T16:42:01Z ntpd[956363]: 64.6.144.6 interface 172.16.180.23 -> 172.16.120.2
```

172.16.120.2 is my vmkernel port for vMotion, management, etc.  172.16.180.23 and 24 are vmkernel ports for iSCSI only (vMotion, management, etc. disabled).

There should be some messages in there similar to this "ntpd[263140]: synchronized to , stratum " but I don't see any.

Any idea of what I might be missing?

EDIT: In fact, if I manually set the time (using Google to get the current time) it will revert to 6 minutes slow after a few seconds.

EDIT 2: Well, the incorrect time was propagating to our domain controller and then out to our workstations.  I disabled VMware Tools time sync to the domain controller, had it resync its time and then resync'd the time to my desktop so that everything was correct.

Now, I am not experiencing the above issue any longer.  So, is it possible that the incorrect time on the domain controller VM was adjusting the time on the host?  I didn't think it went both ways.  Alternatively, would the vSphere Client on my machine update the time on the host?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're mucking about in the support shell to do this, when it's all supported in both the C# client, and web client?

Comment: Just following what VMware's troubleshooting guide (https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1005092) says.  Though I should note that I'm not actually making any changes to the config using the support shell - I use the vSphere Client for that.  I just use the shell to get information.

Comment: Ok, so you're just monitoring NTP from the shell, not configuring it?